# split string by hyphen in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to split following string into two parts using split function of javascript

original string is **'Average Sized' - 'Mega Church!'**       ***(with single quotes)***

please mark that there is a single quote inside the string

and i want to split it by hyphen symbol so the result would be

```
[0] Average Sized 
[1] Mega Church!
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this:

```
"Average Sized - Mega Church!".split(/\s*\-\s*/g)
```

edit:

if you mean the original string INCLUDES the single quotes, this should work:

```
"'Average Sized - Mega Church!'".replace(/^'|'$/g, "").split(/\s*\-\s*/g)
```

if you just meant that the string is defined with single quotes, the original will work.

Answer (score 29):

```
var str = "Average Sized - Mega Church!";
var arr = str.split("-");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var str = "Average Sized - Mega Church!";
var arr = [];

arr = str.split('-');
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest Method is

```
var arr = "'Average Sized'-'Mega Church!'".replace(/'/ig,"").split("-")
```